# Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Target Name/Pods-Target Name-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cocoapods

I am getting two errors,

1. Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Target Name/Pods-Target Name-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'
2. Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Target Name/Pods-Target Name-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist'

Following are the contents of my Podfile,

flutter_application_path = 'flutter module path'

load File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')

target 'Target Name' do

install_all_flutter_pods(flutter_application_path)

end

I have a flutter module which I am using in my project. So for that I am integrating that flutter module through Podfile.

If anyone wants to know about how to embed flutter module in iOS project, Please refer this link
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup

I have tried following solutions,

1. pod deintegrate & pod install
2. Deleting pods folder, podfile.lock, and auto-generated project-name.xcworkspace. Then pod install
3. Deleting the entries in Embed Pods Framework->InputFileLists & OutputFileLists-> Clean Build. (Upon doing this it gives another error of podfile.lock file not in sync. Please do pod install)
4. Deleting derived data -> Clean Build.

I am using Xcode 12.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may try `pod repo update`. Something I do when nothing else is working. Helps maybe 20% of the time, so don't get your hopes up :(

Comment: @hvaughan3 I tried pod repo update. It didn't help me fix the issue. I found out the solution for this. I have posted the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution for this.

We need to make changes in build-debug.xcconfig and build-release.xcconfig.

In buid-debug.xcconfig, make changes like this,

1. Comment this line: #include "../pods-debug.xcconfig"
2. Add this line below the comment: #include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Target Name/Pods-Target Name.debug.xcconfig"

In buid-release.xcconfig, make changes like this,

1. Comment this line: #include "../pods-release.xcconfig"
2. Add this line below the comment: #include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Target Name/Pods-Target Name.release.xcconfig"

Please note, I was facing this issue in Cordova project. I haven't tried this solution in pure native ios project.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` afterwards. Worked for Xcode Cloud pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

in my case i tried

1- `pod repo update /pod deintegrate / pod install`  with no success
then i noticed that inside my `Runner>Flutter` both Debug.xcconfig and Release.xcconfig are missing
so i copied both files from older project
the content of files is

Debug.xcconfig:

```
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

and

Release.xcconfig:

```
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

these steps fixed my project i hope it will fix yours also

Answer (score 0):

In my case i replaced ios folder with newly created app's ios folder and adjust changes on info.plist and project.pbxproj files

Answer (score 0):

@Yash's answer helped me.

I was using Xcode Cloud to build a Flutter project on iOS and encountered the same error.

iOS/Flutter/Release.xcconfig:

Change:

```
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

To:

```
#include? "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```